# Get error when comparing typeof(Dictionary), because Dictionary`2

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, types

I`m working in Unity, and in my game, I want to get variables of objects to give player permission to change them. So, this function do this:

```
public static void GetVariables(GameObject objectToInspect, GameObject configPanel)
    {
        configPanel.GetComponent<Grid>().enabled = false;
        Component[] objectComponents = objectToInspect.GetComponents(typeof(Component));
        foreach (var component in objectComponents)
        {
            foreach (var property in component.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
            {
                if (property.IsDefined(typeof(SerializeField), true))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int id = types[property.PropertyType];
                        switch (id)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                {
                                    GameObject numberChooser = Instantiate(UIs[4], configPanel.transform);
                                    numberChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().property = property;
                                    numberChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().component = component;
                                    break;
                                }
                            case 1:
                                {
                                    GameObject numberChooser = Instantiate(UIs[4], configPanel.transform);
                                    numberChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().property = property;
                                    numberChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().component = component;
                                    break;
                                }
                            case 2:
                                {
                                    GameObject arrayChooser = Instantiate(UIs[0], configPanel.transform);
                                    arrayChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().property = property;
                                    arrayChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().component = component;
                                    break;
                                }
                            case 3:
                                {
                                    GameObject arrayChooser = Instantiate(UIs[0], configPanel.transform);
                                    arrayChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().property = property;
                                    arrayChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().component = component;
                                    break;
                                }
                            case 4:
                                {
                                    GameObject arrayChooser = Instantiate(UIs[0], configPanel.transform);
                                    arrayChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().property = property;
                                    arrayChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().component = component;
                                    break;
                                }
                            case 5:
                                {
                                    GameObject vectorChooser = Instantiate(UIs[6], configPanel.transform);
                                    vectorChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().property = property;
                                    vectorChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().component = component;
                                    break;
                                }
                            case 6:
                                {
                                    GameObject booleanChooser = Instantiate(UIs[2], configPanel.transform);
                                    booleanChooser.GetComponent<BoolChooser>().property = property;
                                    booleanChooser.GetComponent<BoolChooser>().component = component;
                                    break;
                                }
                            case 7:
                                {
                                    GameObject spriteChooser = Instantiate(UIs[5], configPanel.transform);
                                    spriteChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().property = property;
                                    spriteChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().component = component;
                                    break;
                                }
                            case 8:
                                {
                                    GameObject colorChooser = Instantiate(UIs[3], configPanel.transform);
                                    colorChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().property = property;
                                    colorChooser.GetComponent<Chooser>().component = component;
                                    break;
                                }
                            default:
                                {
                                    Debug.Log(property.PropertyType.Name);
                                    break;
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        configPanel.GetComponent<Grid>().enabled = true;
        configPanel.GetComponent<Grid>().OnTransformChildrenChanged();
    }
```

There`s dictionary with types and integers:

```
public static Dictionary<Type, int> types = new Dictionary<Type,int>();
types[typeof(Single)] = 0;
    types[typeof(Int32)] = 1;
    types[typeof(Int32[])] = 2;
    types[typeof(List<Type>)] = 3;
    types[typeof(Dictionary<int, int[]>)] = 4;
    types[typeof(Vector3)] = 5;
    types[typeof(Boolean)] = 6;
    types[typeof(Sprite)] = 7;
    types[typeof(Color)] = 8;
```

But I have a problem with Dictionaries and Lists. System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].get_Item (TKey key) [0x0001e] in <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0

This try to check "Dictionary`2" instead of "Dictionary<int, int[]>".
How I can get Dictionary without "`2" and List without "`1/2/3" at the end?

Comment: I don't think the `Dictionary<int,int[]>` is related to the exception. Where do you get the exception? `int id = types[property.PropertyType];` ? By the way, the backtick and the number are part of the underlying type metadata of the generic types. Unless you're comparing type names textually (a red flag 99.44% of the time), you won't have to deal with the difference.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Please try to reduce the question to a [mre].

Comment: What is the actual instantiated type of the object you have? It is clearly not `Dictionary<int,int[]>`

Comment: I'm get exception at `int id = types[property.PropertyType];`.

I have GameObject with script VisibleVariables attached to it. VisibleVariables do nothing, but have a bunch [SerializeField] variables with "get" and "set".
https://i.imgur.com/jhkLxkj.png

When I'm trying to give this GO as an argument to GetVariables(). So, this thing working for all types of variables, but Dictionary and List; float = Single, int[] = Int32[], but Dictionary<int, int[]> = Dictionary`2.

property.PropertyType == property.PropertyType.Name == Dictionary\`2 or "Dictionary\`2".